# Setting value for a view filter

Tags: views, 8

How do I set a view filter so that the date of item makes it disappear WHEN the event occurs?

Right now when I edit the filter I have it Operator set to 'is greater than or equal to' and the Value set to 'today', but I want it to disappear at the exact time the event is occurring.

What do I put in 'value' for that to happen?

Comment: Did you try "now" as filter value?

Comment: no, but i'm going to try it now! Thanks for the suggestion :) Once the event happens we'll see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

`now` worked. I also discovered `+1` works for one hour before the event.